# What does the context parameter in webpack config really do?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to understand what the `context` parameter in webpack's config file.

In the documentation, it says this:

> The base directory (absolute path!) for resolving the entry option. If
>   output.pathinfo is set, the included **pathinfo is shortened to this
>   directory**.

For example in this code,

```
var config = {
    context: __dirname + '/src',
    entry: ['./index.tsx']
}
```

Is this actually defining the base directory for my entry points? In other words, assuming `__dirname` is `c:\project\`, would my entry point then actually be `c:\project\src\index.tsx`? From what I've tried, it doesn't look like so.

The documentation also mentioned that if `output.pathinfo` was provided, the "included pathinfo is shortened to this directory." I don't understand what it means by "shortened". Does it mean `output.pathinfo` and `context` are the same?